# Change Div Outline onmouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, hover

I am having trouble working with the css and javascript for this... I have several `<div>` with `class="item"`. What I want to do is change the outline of thie  that triggered the action on hover.

I have this CSS:

```
.item {
   width: 118px;
   height: 98px;
   float: left;
   margin: 2px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   outline: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

and this javascript which i found from google

```
$('.item').hover( function() {
   $(this).css('outline', '3px solid blue');
},
function() {
   $(this).css('outline', '3px solid transparent');
});
```

Please help me with this...

Comment: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/KhTBK/1/). Whats the problem?

Comment: did you add the code inside a dom ready handler?

Comment: whether the `.item` elements are created dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you are using jquery when this can be achieved using just CSS:

Using `:hover` css selector :-

```
.item:hover{
     outline-color: blue;
}
```

If you want the solution using jQuery only then you might be missing the following things to do: (*as mentioned by johny in above comments*)

- wrap the code in `$(function(){/*code here*/})`
- use `.on()` to attach a event. (*if the element is added dynamically*)

  ```
  $(function(){
      $('.item').on('hover',  function() {
          $(this).css('outline', '3px solid blue');
      },
      function() {
          $(this).css('outline', '3px solid transparent');
      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 3):

```
.item:HOVER {
   width: 118px;
   height: 98px;
   float: left;
   margin: 2px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   outline: 3px solid blue;
}

try this...
```

Comment: giving just `outline: 3px solid blue;` is enough. and why :hover in caps?

Comment: its not case sensitive
uppercase or lowercase not an issue..
i just edited his code and yes just "outline: 3px solid blue;" is sufficient..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, that should work fine. Additionally, you could do this without any jQuery or Javascript, with simple css:

```
.item:hover
{
    outline: 3px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4eYQ/

Comment: Thanks for responding, you've been very kind

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use jquery's [selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) `$(".item-list'").selectable();` instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for responding! you've been very kind

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**script**

```
$(function(){

  $('.item').hover(
    function(){
       $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function(){
       $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    }
  );

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this css this will work fine

```
.item:hover {
      outline: 3px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: i used this one to set only the outline property... Thank you so much

Comment: who is down voted me, i think he is not try or have no knowledge of css